# Azure Logic app IBM MQ Connector unable to understand how to achieve request-reply pattern

Tags: azure-logic-apps

I am trying to accomplish request-reply pattern for IBM MQ using Azurelogicapp IBM MQ connector. I have tried to research on this but there is very limited documentation for this.

Currently I have used:

send message connector-> To post messages to IBM MQ

Receive Message connector-> To receive message from IBM MQ

But I see few advanced parameters in send message connector like

1. reply-to-Queue
2. persistence
3. MessageID

I understood reply-to-Queue is used to perform request reply pattern.which will eliminate the use of Receive message connector. But I am not sure how to do it as there are no content/Docs for this.

Also I am not able to how the above advanced parameters work.